# Can't insert an element to a MS SQL Server table without identity field in Django

Tags: sql-server, django

I have a legacy table in MS SQL Server in which the ID is not an identity field, and I can't insert entities because it hasn't an identity property. In order to find the error I created a new table with the same characteristics and just two fields: ID and name. When I try to insert a record I get the same message:

> Table 'base_test' does not have the identity property. Cannot perform
> SET operation. (8106) (SQLExecDirectW)

If my table has an identity record it inserts it correctly.

I tried with ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server, ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server, pydobc, mssql, always the same message.

Is it possible that the ODBC driver is not prepared for this situation?

Comment: My model:
class Test(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=False)

Comment: You need to show how you are performing the `INSERT`. Of course it is possible to insert in a table without an `IDENTITY` column

Comment: Are you trying to use SQLAlchemy, by chance? Apparently it assumes that any integer column marked as primary key must also be an identity column, so the error message you're seeing is where it's trying to `SET IDENTITITY_INSERT (table) ON`. This is an extremely bogus thing to be doing from a client because only one table at a time can have this in effect, creating a different kind of concurrency nightmare. Ref: [Microsoft SQL Server (dialect)](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/mssql.html)

Comment: @HoneyBadger the simplest code I could write:
test = Test("hello")
test.save()

Comment: @AlwaysLearning 
I don't think so. I don't know if django-composite-foreignkey or django-viewflow use that library.